# Cambios de color indebidos en background de items

Tags: android-recyclerview, android-adapter

Quiero cambiar el color de fondo de los cardview que representan a un elemento que esté en un estado concreto. Lo consigo, pero el problema es que también me toman el mismo color items siguientes cada nueve o diez posiciones más abajo sin que estén en ese estado que determino.

```
public class AdaptadorListPub extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdaptadorListPub.ViewHolder>
implements OnClickListener {
private OnClickListener listener;
public List<Trayecto> listaTrayectos;
private Activity activity;
public AdaptadorListPub(List<Trayecto> ListaTrayectos, Activity activity)
{
    this.listaTrayectos = ListaTrayectos;
    this.activity = activity;

}
@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.lista_publicados,
            parent, false);
    view.setOnClickListener(this);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
    return viewHolder;
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(
        @NonNull final AdaptadorListPub.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    Trayecto trayecto = listaTrayectos.get(position);
    String codTrayecto = trayecto.getCodTrayecto();
    holder.txvCodTrayecto.setText(codTrayecto);
    String codConductor = trayecto.getCodConductor();
    holder.txvCodConductor.setText(codConductor);
    String origen = cargaDireccion(trayecto.getOrigenObj());
    holder.txvOrigen.setText(origen);
    String destino = cargaDireccion(trayecto.getDestinoObj());
    holder.txvDestino.setText(destino);
    String fecha = trayecto.getDia() + "/" + trayecto.getMes() + "/" + trayecto.getAnho();
    holder.txvFecha.setText(trayecto.getFechaBreve());
    String hora = trayecto.getHora() + ":" + trayecto.getMinuto();
    holder.txvHora.setText(hora);
    String nombre = listaTrayectos.get(position).getNombre();
    holder.txvNombre.setText(nombre);
    Double precio = trayecto.getPrecio();
    holder.txvPrecio.setText(precio.toString() + "€");
    cambiaColor(holder.cdvPublicados, position);
}
private String cargaDireccion(Direccion direccion)
{
    return direccion.getCalle() + ", " + direccion.getNumero() +
            " " + direccion.getMunicipio();
}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return listaTrayectos.size();
}

public void setOnClickListener(OnClickListener listener)
{
    this.listener = listener;
}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (listener != null)
        listener.onClick(v);
}
public  class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private TextView txvOrigen, txvDestino, txvFecha, txvHora, txvNombre, txvPrecio,
        txvCodTrayecto, txvCodConductor;
    private CardView cdvPublicados;
    public ViewHolder(View view)
    {
        super(view);
        txvCodTrayecto = (TextView)view.findViewById( R.id.txvCodTrayecto);
        txvCodConductor = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txvCodConductor);
        txvOrigen = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txvOrigen);
        txvDestino = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txvDestino);
        txvFecha = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txvFecha);
        txvHora = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txvHora);
        txvNombre = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txvNombre);
        txvPrecio = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txvPrecio);
        cdvPublicados = (CardView)view.findViewById(R.id.cdvPublicados);
    }
}
public void cambiaColor(CardView cardView, int position)
{
    switch(listaTrayectos.get(position).getEstadoTrayecto())
    {
        case Constantes.ACEPTADO:
            cardView.setBackgroundColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.aceptado));
            break;
        case Constantes.COMPLETO:
            cardView.setBackgroundColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.completo));
            break;
        case Constantes.PENDIENTE:
            cardView.setBackgroundColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.alerta));
            break;
        case Constantes.SOLICITADO:
            //cardView.setBackgroundColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.solicitado));
            cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
            break;

        case Constantes.RECHAZADO:
            cardView.setBackgroundColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.rechazado));
    }
}
```

}

Por ejemplo: la intención es que cuando un trayecto esté en estado "SOLICITADO" el fondo del cardview se ponga verde; se pone verde, pero también se pone verde el fondo del cardview de nueve o diez posiciones más abajo (que no está en estado "SOLICITADO") y así cada nueve o diez posiciones. Al desplazar los elementos, hacia arriba y hacia abajo, alguna vez me ha ocurrido que algún item que en la primera pasada no estaba en verde en la segunda pasada sí, sin que haya podido cambiar el estado y sin tener que ponerse en verde.
He comprobado de tres maneras distintas que el estado de los trayectos son los que se supone deben ser, por lo que sólo se me ocurre que el problema pueda tener algo que ver con esto: https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/render?hl=es-419#common-jank ; pero no acabo de entenderlo como para saber qué probar para ir encontrando una solución.

Quiero aprovechar la aplicación para encontrar trabajo como desarrollador, pero un fallo así da mala imagen.

Comment: Me parece correcta la forma como lo realizas, solo imprime la posición y el tipo de trayecto, me parece que hay objetos en la lista que indican un tipo de trayecto que provocan se pinte de color verde otra celda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¡SOLUCIONADO!
Al final he solucionado el problema usando *if*, *if else* y (importante) *else*. Usando *default* en el *switch* seguía con el mismo problema; y sin usar *else* también.

```
public void cambiaColor(CardView cardView, int estadoTrayecto)
{
    if(estadoTrayecto == Constantes.ACEPTADO)
        cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.aceptado));
    else if(estadoTrayecto == Constantes.COMPLETO)
        cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.completo));
    else if(estadoTrayecto == Constantes.PENDIENTE)
        cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.alerta));
    else if(estadoTrayecto == Constantes.SOLICITADO)
        cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.solicitado));
    else if(estadoTrayecto == Constantes.RECHAZADO)
        cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.rechazado));
    else
        cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    /*switch(estadoTrayecto)
    {
        case Constantes.ACEPTADO:
            cardView.setBackgroundColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.aceptado));
            break;
        case Constantes.COMPLETO:
            cardView.setBackgroundColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.completo));
            break;
        case Constantes.PENDIENTE:
            cardView.setBackgroundColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.alerta));
            break;
        case Constantes.SOLICITADO:
            cardView.setBackgroundColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.solicitado));
            break;

        case Constantes.RECHAZADO:
            cardView.setBackgroundColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.rechazado));
            break;
        default:
            cardView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    }*/
}
```

Se ve que *reciclerview* con *switch* no se entiende bien; e incluso con *if* hay que añadir *else*, ya que parece que no siempre toma bien el color por defecto.
Muchas gracias a todos los que se hayan interesado por mi caso.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que se realiza en este caso es el tipo de objeto que se mostraría en la lista, en este caso `Trayecto`, tenga una propiedad, la cual determine el color, al detectar la posición del objeto dentro de `onBindViewHolder()` pintas la celda usando `.setBackgroundColor()`.

De acuerdo a lo que veo en tu código original, me parece que lo estás realizando. Comentas:

> se pone verde, pero también se pone verde el fondo del cardview de
> nueve o diez posiciones más abajo (que no está en estado "SOLICITADO")
> y así cada nueve o diez posiciones.

en este caso te sugiero imprimas la posición y el estado de trayecto, si otra celda cambia de color es que seguramente tiene un tipo de trayecto que hace que pinte la celda de ese color.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(
        @NonNull final AdaptadorListPub.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    Trayecto trayecto = listaTrayectos.get(position);
    String codTrayecto = trayecto.getCodTrayecto();
    holder.txvCodTrayecto.setText(codTrayecto);
    String codConductor = trayecto.getCodConductor();
    holder.txvCodConductor.setText(codConductor);
    String origen = cargaDireccion(trayecto.getOrigenObj());
    holder.txvOrigen.setText(origen);
    String destino = cargaDireccion(trayecto.getDestinoObj());
    holder.txvDestino.setText(destino);
    String fecha = trayecto.getDia() + "/" + trayecto.getMes() + "/" + trayecto.getAnho();
    holder.txvFecha.setText(trayecto.getFechaBreve());
    String hora = trayecto.getHora() + ":" + trayecto.getMinuto();
    holder.txvHora.setText(hora);
    String nombre = listaTrayectos.get(position).getNombre();
    holder.txvNombre.setText(nombre);
    Double precio = trayecto.getPrecio();
    holder.txvPrecio.setText(precio.toString() + "€");
    
    //cambiaColor(holder.cdvPublicados, position);
 
    Log.i("COLOR", "Posición: " + position + " estado trayecto: " + trayecto.getEstadoTrayecto()); 
    //*Cambia color de acuerdo al tipo de trayecto.
    switch(trayecto.getEstadoTrayecto())
    {
        case Constantes.ACEPTADO:
            holder.cdvPublicados.setBackgroundColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.aceptado));
            break;
        case Constantes.COMPLETO:
            holder.cdvPublicados.setBackgroundColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.completo));
            break;
        case Constantes.PENDIENTE:
            holder.cdvPublicados.setBackgroundColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.alerta));
            break;
        case Constantes.SOLICITADO:
            //holder.cdvPublicados.setBackgroundColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.solicitado));
            holder.cdvPublicados.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
            break;

        case Constantes.RECHAZADO:
            holder.cdvPublicados.setBackgroundColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.rechazado));
    }   

}
```

Comment: Lo he comprobado también como dices pero, de todas las formas que lo compruebo, me sale que cada elemento está en el estado que se supone que está. 
Se me pasó mencionar que al desplazar los elementos, hacia arriba y hacia abajo, alguna vez me ha ocurrido que algún item que en la primera pasada no estaba en verde en la segunda pasada sí, sin que haya podido cambiar el estado.
Investigando me ha parecido que el problema puede venir por aquí: https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/render?hl=es-419#common-jank ; pero no acabo de entenderlo como para saber qué probar.

Comment: ¿Las propiedades de los elementos de ListaTrayectos cambian continuamente?, si es así, es muy importante llamar adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); al actualizar la información.

Comment: No, ya que, al no estar explotando la app, sólo la uso yo y los únicos cambios los hago yo, pero me interesa estudiar el método, ya que me acabará haciendo falta.

Comment: No, pero ya lo he solucionado sustituyendo el "switch" por "if", "else if" y "else".
Muchas gracias por todo. 
Cualquier cosa que te parezca añadir estaré encantado de revisarla.